# Getting errors in Apply Mapping Pipeline Step when running pipeline batch

Tags: data-exchange-framework

I am getting the following errors when running a pipeline batch using the *Sitecore Provider for Data Exchange Framework v1.3* and using *Data Exchange Framework v1.3 rev 170206*:

```
3/10/2017 9:46:28 PM    ERROR    Pipeline step processing will abort because mapping set failed. (pipeline step: Apply Mapping, mappings that succeeded: 0, mappings that failed: 2)

3/10/2017 9:46:28 PM    ERROR    Pipeline step processing will abort because mapping set failed. (pipeline step: Apply Mapping, mappings that succeeded: 0, mappings that failed: 2)

3/10/2017 9:46:28 PM    INFO    2 elements were iterated. (pipeline: Retrieve Resource Groups from Azure, pipeline step: Iterate Results from Azure and Run Pipeline)
```

In the logs, I have more of the same followed by some messages telling me Sitecore item properties were skipped (they are pretty generic and not really worth the SSE real-estate).

Note that my items *are* being created and with the correct names (as read from the external service), but their field values are blank. The pipeline batch that I'm running is configured to map single-language data.

Does anyone know what could be causing this issue and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your *Sitecore Item Field Value Accessor Items* (the Sitecore Provider items that you created to point at the Sitecore fields that the data should map to) to make sure that you have not set the "Language" field. This field should only be set for multi-language mappings, otherwise the errors in the OP will be logged.

[image: Indicating "Language" field to be left blank]

Note that I have filed a Sitecore Support ticket to report this issue as a bug. I will update this post if/when I get a response and/or reference number back.

**UPDATE:** I filed a ticket with Sitecore Support and requested that they add some help text in the field's "Title" to help consumers avoid this issue. They got back to me and explained that the solution that I posted here was correct and that while this is the expected behavior adding the help text is a good idea and has been registered as a wish. They provided the reference number 154583 for the wish.

Comment: Thank you very much.You save my day.There should have been more details provided in the log at least.